# Can the dimension of std::array be read from command line arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, std

I have a C++ code where I decided to use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` and I want the size of the array to be read from command line.

In practice, this can be summarized with the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  std::size_t my_size;
  {
    std::istringstream is{argv[1]};
    is >> my_size;
  }
 
  std::cout << my_size<<std::endl;
  std::array<int,my_size> a;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error, which is due to the fact that `my_size` must be known at compile time.

> error: the value of ‘my_size’ is not usable in a constant expression
> 14 |   std::array<int,my_size> a;

Is there any way to let the size of an `std::array` to be given from command line? Or should I definitely use other containers? As dynamic arrays on the heap, or `std::vector` ?

Comment: not possible with `std::array`. use `std::vector` instead

Comment: No, as the error shows, the size of `std::array` must be constant, so for this you'll need something like `std::vector`.

Comment: @anastaciu somehow we are missing an array container whose size is only fixed once created. I know too little about `std::vector` internals to judge if there would be benefits compared to simply wrapping `std::vector` and leaving out anything that changes size / capacity

Comment: @idclev463035818, agreed, they seem to think it's good enough as it is, it would be nice to have something like that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types and arrays sizes in particular must be known at compile time, hence the answer is: No.

You can implement some mapping from a runtime value to a compile-time constant. Something along the line of

```
size_t size;
std::cin >> size;
if (size == 10) {
     std::array<int,10> x;
     // use x
} else if (size == 20) [
     std::array<int,20> y;
     // use y
}
```

However, this is of very limited use, because `x` and `y` are of different type. When the size is only known at runtime it is easier to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in your snippet you're reading from std input, which is different from using `std::istringstream`. I mean, I was interested in using stringstream

Comment: @VoB thats not really relevant. They are both `istream`s and the compiler can impossible know what value will be read from the stream. Replace `std::cin` with a `std::istringstream` and nothing else changes on the answer

Comment: okay. So if I don't know "a priori" the possible size, (meaning that it may be whatever the usel like) I should do a for with inside lots of ifs in order to catch all the possible cases , right? I agree this is totally nonsense, and indeed I will switch to `std::vector`, but I just ask this for the sake of completeness

Comment: @VoB no you should not do that. I only mentioned it because sometimes this is the way to go (but probably not here). If you want an array with size that is only known at runtime use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a relative small size to a constant.
In C++17 it can be solved this way.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

constexpr std::size_t MAX_SIZE = 10;

template <class T, class F, T... I>
bool to_const(T value, F&& fn, std::integer_sequence<T, I...>) {
    return (
        (value == I && (fn(std::integral_constant<T, I>{}), true))
        || ... // or continue
    );
}

template <class T, class F>
bool to_const(T value, F&& fn) {
    return value <= MAX_SIZE &&
        to_const(value, fn, std::make_integer_sequence<T, MAX_SIZE + 1>{});
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  std::size_t my_size;
  {
    std::istringstream is{argv[1]};
    is >> my_size;
  }
 
  std::cout << my_size<<std::endl;

  bool found = to_const(my_size, [](auto N)
  {
      std::array<int, N> a;
  });

  return 0;
}
```